# Аналогия switch()

Tags: java, switch

Нашёл сборник задач и прорешиваю его на java ради интереса. Столкнулся с проблемой.

```
switch (input) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print(ts.task_1());
            break;
        case 2:
            ts.task_2();
            break;
        case 3:
            ts.task_3();
            break;
        case 4:
            ts.task_4();
            break; //и так далее до 1000
```

Можно ли как-то изменить подход к реализации класса для вызова задач в большом количестве?

Comment: `HashMap<Int, Runnable>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться рефлексией:

```
 TS ts;
 Class clazz=ts.getClass();
 if(input==1)
    System.out.print(ts.task_1());
 else {
   //получаем ссылку на метод с именем task_*()
   Method method=clazz.getDeclaredMethod("task_"+input, null); 
   if(method!=null)  //вызываем метод
      method.invoke(ts, null);
 }
```

Comment: А как быть с `1`?

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: хм... А что делать с `237`, где будет, например, `finalCountdown.start(10);`?

Comment: а что делать если в `12980` будет `call fuck_em_all()`?

Comment: Задуматься, откуда в Java появился оператор `call` :D